# Cursor to String

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm new to android, and I don't know why I am getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested with a size of 0. I'm trying to display it on another class using listview. Here are my codes:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    position = position + 1;

    Cursor a = MainActivity.sqldb
            .rawQuery("Select name from " + MainActivity.tblpb
                    + " where _pid = " + position + ";", null);

    String aa = a.getString(a.getColumnIndex("name"));


    Cursor b = MainActivity.sqldb
            .rawQuery("Select phone from " + MainActivity.tblpb
                    + " where _pid = " + position + ";", null);

    String bb = b.getString(b.getColumnIndex("phone"));

    Intent next = new Intent (this, ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivity(next);

}
```

I know that there's something really wrong here. And I wonder what it is.

Create Table:

```
sqldb = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbpb, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    sqldb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + tblpb
            + " (_pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, phone INTEGER);");
```

Insert Table:

```
sqldb.execSQL("Insert into " + tblpb
                        + " (name, phone) Values ('" + x + "' , '"
                        + y + "' );");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
    long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String aa = null;
    String bb = null;

    // do not alter the position, DB starts the same position as ItemClick for
    // adapter view
    // position = position + 1;

    Cursor a = MainActivity.sqldb
        .rawQuery("Select name from " + MainActivity.tblpb
                + " where _pid = " + position + ";", null);

    if(a != null){
         // Force cursor to position 0
         if(a.moveToFirst()){
              // make sure the column actually exists
              aa = a.getString(a.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
              Log.d("Cursor A - Name", "name column val: "+ aa);
         }else{
              Log.d("Cursor A", "cursor A failed to move to first");
         }
    }else{
         Log.d("Cursor A null", "cannot access cursor A");
    }

    Cursor b = MainActivity.sqldb.rawQuery("Select phone from " + MainActivity.tblpb + " where _pid = " + position + ";", null);

   if(b != null){
         // Force cursor to position 0
         if(b.moveToFirst()){
              // make sure the column actually exists
              bb = b.getString(b.getColumnIndexOrThrow("phone"));
              Log.d("Cursor B - Phone", "phone column val: "+ bb);
         }else{
              Log.d("Cursor B", "cursor B failed to move to first");
         }
    }else{
         Log.d("Cursor B null", "cannot access cursor B");
    }

    Intent next = new Intent (this, ThirdActivity.class);
    next.putExtra("NAME", aa);
    next.putExtra("PHONE", bb);
    startActivity(next);

}
```

Then in your second Activity do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_file);

  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(extras != null){
      String aa = extras.getString("NAME");
      String bb = extras.getString("PHONE");

      // Since you cannot tell if these are null check them
      if(aa != null){
        // ... Use on your TextView

      }
      // Since you cannot tell if these are null check them
      if(bb != null){
       // ... Use on your TextView

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It didn't display anything.

Comment: did your logcat output print anything? see above edits

Comment: on the thirdactivity class, is it right to set the textviews as these : tvname.setText(SecondActivity.aa);
tvphone.setText(SecondActivity.bb); , I mean aa and bb are both static.

Comment: no, you must call Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); and retrieve the values see above...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that. can you tell me how to. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hmm, it gives me an error: Call requires API level 12 (current min is 8): android.os.Bundle#getString

Comment: if(aa != null){
         tvname.setText(SecondActivity.aa);
        }
        else
        {
         tvname.setText("HELLO!");
        } ...it gives me hello, which means the extra is null.

Comment: your select statement is bad then, you are not getting the Cursor back correctly. add the setup database code to your question.

Comment: But I can see the name column on my listview. btw, I already have updated my post.

Comment: Did you populate anything into the Database? Maybe you have no name or phone actually there... so the Cursor cannot query items that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are trying to access the first element (index 0) of an empty list (size 0) meaning your queries are returning no results. Make sure your queries are correct.

**EDIT:**

It's also a good idea to call cursor.moveToFirst() and check its result before doing any operations on the data from a query.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29

Comment: I got rid of the error by putting moveToFirst but when I toast it, it displays nothing.

Comment: @ken Toasting it will damage your phone. I assume you mean test. Can you *add* your new code to your question, please?

Comment: Your query is still returning no results. You'll have to make sure your DB is populated with data and that your query is returning data. If the device you are testing on is rooted you can get the .db file from data/data/<your.package.name>/databases/yourDataBase.db and open it using any SQLite manager to ensure your DB has correct data